# Is TTL implemented in Pika?

Tags: pika

I'd like my queue to drop messages not processed within a certain time.

I already do this in the consumer by recording the publish time. However, in the case that no-one is subcribing, it would be better for the queue to simply drop stale messages.

Can I set a expiry time (TTL) in messages in Pika. The RabbitMQ docs talk about it but i don't see TTL references in the Pika docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the per message TTL using the expiration flag on the BasicProperties object, as seen in the pika documentation [here](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.BasicProperties).

Using it would look something like this.

```
channel.basic_publish(
    exchange='',
    routing_key='hello_world',
    properties=pika.BasicProperties(
        expiration='60000',
    ),
    body='my message'
)
```

Keep in mind that the `expiration` policy is expressed using milliseconds as string, so `60000` would translate to 60 seconds.

You can read more about message based TTL and it's caveats [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).